# Load a huge sparse array and save it back as a dense array

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix

I have a huge sparse matrix. I would like to save the *dense* equivalent one into file system.

The problem is the memory limit on my machine.

My original idea is:

1. convert `huge_sparse_matrix` to `ndarray` by `np.asarray(huge_sparse_matrix)`
2. assign values
3. save it back to file system

However, at step `1`, Python raises `MemoryError`.

One possible approach in my mind is:

1. create a chunk of the dense array
2. assign values from the corresponding sparse one
3. save the dense array chunk back to file system
4. repeat 1-3

But how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the scipy.sparse function to read sparse matrix and then convert it to numpy , see documentation here  [scipy.sparse docs and examples](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think np.asarray() is not really the function you're looking for.
You might try the SciPy matrix format cco_matrix() (coordinate formatted matrix).
[scipy.sparse.coo_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)

this format allows to save huge sparse matrices in very little memory.
furthermore there are many mathematical scipy functions which also work with this matrix format.

The matrix representation in this format are basically three lists:

- row: the index of the row
- col: the index of the column
- data: the value at this position

hope that helped, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The common and most straightforward answer to memory problems is: Do not create objects, use an iterator or a generator.

If I understand correctly, you have a sparse matrix and you want to transform it into a list representation. Here's a sample code:

```
def iter_sparse_matrix ( m, d1, d2 ):
    for i in xrange(d1):
        for j in xrange(d2):
            if m[i][j]:
                yield ( i, j, m[i][j] )

dense_array = list(iter_sparse_matrix(m, d1, d2))
```

You might also want to look here:

http://cvxopt.org/userguide/matrices.html#sparse-matrices

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong the problem you have is that the `dense` of the sparse matrix does **not** fit in your memory, and thus, you are not able to save it.

What I would suggest you is to use [HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html). HDF5 handles big data in disk passing it to memory only when needed.

I something like this should work:

```
import h5py

data = # your sparse matrix
cx = data.tocoo() # coo sparse representation
```

This will create your data matrix (of zeros) in disk.

```
f = h5py.File('dset.h5','w')
dataset = f.create_dataset("data", data.shape)
```

Fill the matrix with the sparse data:

```
dataset[cx.row, cx.col] = cx.data
```

Add any modifications you want to dataset:

```
dataset[something, something] = something
```

And finally, save it:

```
file.close()
```

The way HDF5 works I think is perfect for your needs. The matrix is stored always in disk, so it doesn't require memory, however, you can operate with it as if it was a standard numpy matrix (indexing, slicing, `np.(..)` operations and so on) and the h5py driver will send the parts of the matrix that you need to memory (never the whole matrix unless you specifically require it with something like `data[:, :]`).

PS: I'm assuming your sparse matrix is one of the `scipy`'s sparse matrix. If not replace `cx.row`, `cx.col` and `cx.data` from the ones provided by your matrix representation (should be something like it).